# Custom error message on basket page

Tags: magento-1.8, module, checkout, redirect

What I know how to do:

I have set up an observer to catch the event "Go to Checkout".Everything seems to work fine.I can make a check that I want and redirect back to the page with an error message.

What I don't know:

I want to have a better message than the error.Ideally I would like to make a propose to customer and return something like a table and a custom message and not the default error styled message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you what custom design for a single type of error message?

Comment: Yes, that could do.

Comment: What stops you from submitting HTML to the error message?!

Answer (score 1):

Just put in the error message whatever you want.

The template is this: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/core/messages.phtml` and I don't see any reason to not just deliver whatever you want.